# Float and double error in class c++

Tags: c++, class

I keep getting this error...

```
lab11a.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
lab11a.cpp:120:34: error: no matching function for call to ‘SafeArray::GetElement(int&, double)’
lab11a.cpp:120:34: note: candidate is:
lab11a.cpp:48:6: note: bool SafeArray::GetElement(int, float&) const
lab11a.cpp:48:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘double’ to ‘float&’
lab11a.cpp:121:38: error: no matching function for call to ‘SafeArray::GetElement(int&, double)’
lab11a.cpp:121:38: note: candidate is:
lab11a.cpp:48:6: note: bool SafeArray::GetElement(int, float&) const
lab11a.cpp:48:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘double’ to ‘float&’
```

This is the code that I have in my interface for this method:

```
bool GetElement(const int i, float & Value) const;
```

This is the code in my implementation:

```
bool SafeArray::GetElement(const int i, float & Value) const 
{
    bool Success = false;
    if ((i >= 0) && (i < SIZE))
    {
        Success = true;
        Value = Array[i];
    }
    return Success;
}
```

This is the code in my main program:

```
for (int i = -5; i < 24; i++)
{
    data1.GetElement(i, i * 0.1);
    if (data1.GetElement(i, i * 0.1) == true)
        cout << "get " << i << " " << i * 0.1 << endl;
}
```

Comment: In your interface and implementation change the parameter `value` to type float - your compiler may have a high warning level.

Answer (score 4):

Your function `GetElement` takes a reference to a `float` and writes a value there.  However, you call it with `i * 0.1`, this is an unnamed temporary which cannot be passed for parameter `float & Value`.  Think about it:  Within `GetElement` you write something into `Value`, where should this number end up when you pass `i * 0.1` as `Value`?  Doesn't make sense and won't work.  You have to pass a named variable of the correct type here, so the function can write something into it.

Comment: I don't understand what the type should be. It is a float in the method so I don't see why it says it is a double.

Comment: @savannaalexis You do call it with a `double`, `i*0.1`, but you should call it with a `float &`.  What the hell are you doing here anyway?  What's this `i*0.1` supposed to do?

Comment: It says it cannot convert `double` to `float&`. `i * 0.1` evaluates to a double by default, but this is irrelevant. You are trying to take the address of a temporary, which is what the `&` operator does. Not allowed.

Comment: @pentadecagon I am just trying to print certain values in a range if the method returns Success as true.

Comment: Well, even if it would compile, somehow, that value `i*0.1` you pass into that function would be ignored.  This function `GetElement` never actually *reads* what you pass as `Value`, it only writes there.

Comment: Do this: `float f = ((float) i) * 0.1` and then call your function using `f` as the second parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Your `GetElement` modifies its second parameter. How are you expecting it to assign to `Value` when `Value` is `i * 0.1`?

You could make the parameter `float const &`, but then you couldn't modify it in the function.

I think you need to think about what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want your main loop to look like this:

```
for (int i = -5; i < 24; i++)
{
    float f;
    if (data1.GetElement(i, f) == true)
        cout << "get " << i << " " << f << endl;
}
```

This way you can pass `f` by reference to your `GetElement` method. You can get the address of `f` (which is what the `&` symbol does), but you cannot get the address of a temporary (`i*0.1`).